# Number of min-cuts of a graph

Tags: graphs, algorithm-analysis

It can be shown that every graph G has at most $\binom{n}{2}$ min-cuts.
It follows from Karger’s algorithm Analysis.

Is there a different combinatorial proof of this fact? Was this known before Karger’s paper?

Comment: This question has been answered [here on Theoretical Computer Science](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3322/number-of-mincuts-of-a-graph-without-using-kargers-algorithm)

Comment: Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 1):

An earlier proof that associates to an arbitrary graph G a certain "structural graph" was shown by Dinitz, Karzanov and Lomonosov in 1976 [1].

---

[1] Dinitz, E. A., Karzanov, A. V., & Lomonosov, M. V. (1976). On the structure of the system of minimum edge cuts in a graph. *Issledovaniya po Diskretnoi Optimizatsii*, 290-306.